# facebook already liked how can I call something

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Here my following problem:
I set up the like button and it works properly if I liked or not liked by FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',... and  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove',...

But I don't know how to call some action in the following condition:
I load my webpage, and I'm not yet logged with facebook, then I push the like button and I'm redirected to facebook login. After I logged in I get the button liked because I have already liked the page. Under this condition how can I call some action if the button is already liked and I don't do any further click to call FB.Event.subscribe?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to know if the user liked the page?

Comment: Be aware that Like Gating in any form is not allowed any more.

Comment: I'm just using that to automatic login in my application without any manual action. If user already liked then is forwarded to my app without do anything manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is intentionally not possible without the `user_likes` permission, and that permission isn't granted to apps which are using it to check if a user likes a specific page, or which otherwise aren't providing utility to the user based on the likes data